# Django register form validation for javascript

Tags: javascript, django, validation, django-forms, preventdefault

In django i followed form method is model form i not validate in backend only validate frontend using javascript but if click the submit button the data is not store to database how to fix

I tried to submit the data in database but if I click data is validate but not store to database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.